# Is there a value indexed collection in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, data-structures

My question is a simple one: Is there collection in JavaScript that can index on the value of an object, allows retrieval by object value and can provide the keys as an object if requested?

My use case is wanting a container that can index by coordinate e.g. x, y, z. (yes I know I could create a 3D array).

I am more than aware that a standard object indexes and retrieves by string, setting the `toString()` function for an object will let you set and retrieve (somewhat) transparently.

I am also aware of `Map<key, value>` which uses an arbitrary type as key, but then uses standard === to compare keys meaning that two objects that are equal in value do not map to the same value.

Essentially what I want is a Map that actually uses the value of the key, rather than the object identity to retrieve and provide values. This seems to me like it would be a very common use case but I can't seem to find any npm libraries that satisfy it. I don't really want to roll my own so is there a library or something that I can use to achieve my goal? I assume my search terms are just heavily overloaded.

Some simple code to demonstrate:

```
class Coord {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    toString() { return `${this.x}, ${this.y}`; }
}

let valueMap = new Map();
valueMap.set(new Coord(1, 1), `A set value`);
console.log(valueMap.get(new Coord(1, 1))); // prints 'undefined', 
                                            // want to get: 'A set value'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the value of an object"?

Comment: I think he means he wants his Map to do a value comparison and not a reference comparison

Comment: Sounds like you just want something which transforms the passed key into a string, in which case a plain object would seem to do the trick?

Comment: As in the example of a coordinate, if all the properties are equal then the objects are equal.

Comment: @xbonez sure, but I repeat the question: what is the "value" of an object?

Comment: @radman if you're looking for something like you get in Java with definable `.equals()` etc, no. You'd have to implement it yourself.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, with a standard object you can't iterate the keys as the original object, because it only stores strings. You could do a manual toString fromString step which is what I was going to do, but don't want to.

Comment: @Pointy, I realise it doesn't exist in the JS standard, my question really is: are there any libraries on npm etc. Surely someone else has implemented this before?!

Comment: You could create a `Coord()` factory that returns fixed objects for specific coordinates, and then you could just use native `Map`. Generally questions looking for external resource recommendations are closed on SO however.

Comment: @Pointy, not a bad suggestion as a workaround, but I'd still like to know if there are any libraries that have implemented the data structure I'm talking about

Comment: https://github.com/shevchenkobn/eq-collections#hashmap If you don't understand the role that both a hashcode and equals function play in a hashtable, then you'll probably [need to do some reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Comment: @spender, hash is the index and equals is for resolving collisions :)

Comment: So this might help you on your way: https://github.com/puleos/object-hash

Comment: And don't forget that hashtables ***require*** you not to mutate your keys, otherwise bad things happen. Best to make them immutable or [`deep-freeze`](https://github.com/substack/deep-freeze) them.

Comment: @spender, you might want to put that into an answer so that I can reward you appropriately ;)

Comment: Nah. It's just an opinion of which software to use. I should really offer a close vote.

Comment: @spender, Close vote because, I'm essentially asking for a library recommendation?

Comment: @spender, I'm not really sure I agree that it should be closed on those grounds, at the very least it has an answer. Which is that it isn't supported by JavaScript, but there are ways to achieve the result. I feel like an answer like that would be useful to others, but probably the rule lawyers will win out and the close will go ahead.

Comment: I think that Proxy (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) would best fit your requirements..

Comment: Sounds like you want to retrieve an entry dynamically by any value of the entry. If you are working on web application, modern browser does come with IndexedDB. https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-indexeddb

Comment: @radman So, I didn't vote, but my potential answer would be a software/library recommendation, mainly off the back of searches that I did in (favorite search engine here). Searching for `hashcode hashtable npm` was very informative.

Comment: If your question stands the test of time, I'll come back and post an answer. Would quite like to try it out at my end too. I have a project that would benefit greatly from "deep" keys.

Comment: @spender, I've tried out the hashmap library you linked and it works as advertised. For me just using a string rep of a coord was perfect e.g. 'x,y'. I've also written my own basic version, which was very simple once I had the right idea. I'll probably end up answering this myself I think...

Answer (score 2):

[Immutable.js](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/) provides this, but it requires that you only use immutable's types and primitives. This would mean using Immutable's `Record` types instead of classes<sup>*</sup>. Your example in this case would look like this:

```
const { Record, Map } = require('immutable');
const Coord = Record({ a: 0, b: 0 }); // Record fields have default values

const valueMap = new Map().set(Coord(1, 1), `A set value`);
console.log(valueMap.get(Coord(1, 1))); // Logs "A set value"
```

Immutable.js might not be exactly what you want due to its collections all being, well, immutable. Each operation returns a new collection rather than modifying the original. Fortunately, due to the magic of structural sharing, this is much faster than one might expect.

I have seen a number of alternatives, but they have all either been implemented incorrectly (such as assuming uniqueness of hashes, along the lines of your `toString` example) or have had severe complexity or performance issues when composing maps. For example, Immutable.js allows you to use a map (or set, or list, or map of sets, etc) as a key in another map. The few libraries I've seen which correctly take a hash and equality function as arguments to a map either leak this complexity to the end-user or have much worse performance in this case. Finally, libraries which depend on hash values may run into problems if the stored object is mutated, so using a library which enforces immutability can help to avoid footguns.

If Immutable.js isn't to your liking, there are some similar libraries available. [Mori](http://swannodette.github.io/mori/) was the original immutability-with-structural-sharing library in JS and provides several data structures with value semantics (including maps), but is based on Clojure and has a very non-idiomatic interface for JavaScript. Both of these libraries use hash array mapped tries to provide an efficient implementation of immutable structures, and this type is available in [hamt.js](https://github.com/mattbierner/hamt). However, hamt is very bare-bones, and provides a more challenging and less composable interface than the previous two.

---

<sup>*</sup>Technically you can use your own class by implementing the [Value Object interface](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/ValueObject) and putting an `equals` and `hashCode` method on your classes, but I believe you may run into problems if your objects are mutated while inside of Immutable.js collections, so using Records is probably safer anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Two Object are equal if this two object points to same reference. Also there is no point in getting string value from Object reference. You can set this string in Object.